# Initializing a vector<std::string> in uniform initialization

Tags: c++11, uniform-initialization

I am using the following code

```
class test
{
public:
    test(std::vector<std::string> str)
    {
        auto a = str[0];
        a = "B";
    }
    test()
    {
    }
    const std::multimap<int,  std::multimap<int, test>> _var= {
        {0x01,  {
                    {
                        0x0f, std::vector<std::string>{"A", "B", "C", "D"}
                    }
        }
        }
    };
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    std::cout << "Done";
}
```

The above code builds fine however I get the bad access when I run it. I attached the call stack. Any suggestions why I am getting that error ? or how I can fix it ? Seems like its a constant loop.

[image]

Comment: Where is the error? The code  complies fine for me.

Comment: Its not about compiling its a bad access now. Seems like its constant loop or something during initialization

Comment: try running the code

Comment: Tried it. Normal termination. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using clang. Xcode

Comment: Try this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/  It says segmentation fault

Comment: You have an object of type `test` that owns an object of type `test` that owns an object of type `test` that owns an object of type `test`, ad infinitum. Where do you expect memory for all these objects to come from?

Comment: Interesting that gcc did not catch this. http://cpp.sh/7iaha

Comment: @cplusplusrat MSVC did not aswell, just tried out of curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a case of infinite recursion, leading to stack overflow.

Create an instance of `test` -->
Initialize `_var` -->
Create an instance of `test` -->
Initialize `_var` -->

and so on.